# How can I pause resume of all thread?

Tags: c++, multithreading, cpu-usage, resume, pause

My use case: A process -> request pause/resume(via IPC) -> B process

My purpose is to save CPU usage of B process when B process is background.
Because all threads of B process are consuming CPU usage. 
So that I want to pause/restart all threads of B process when I wanted.

Q1) how can I pause/resume of all thread in B process?

Following is just my first idea, But I am not sure that is a good way to resolve this situation.

If you know a good solution for this, please let me know your advice.

```
<main thread of B process>
while(1)
{
 mCondition.wait(lock);
 //all thread are create & run in here
}

<handler thread of  B process>
if(request resume)
 mCondition.notify_one();
else
 //terminate all thread of B process
```

=> This idea is a way to terminate all threads and recreate all threads.

Comment: You should mention your platform. The C standard doesn't talk much about IPC, AFAIK.

Answer (score 0):

On POSIX platforms, you can simply `kill(targetPid, SIG{STOP,CONT})` the target processm and it'll pause/resume all of its threads.

Answer (score 0):

There is not really a very "cross-platform" way of terminating threads.

As you are implementing a pause mechanism (looks like a conditional_variable? I'll just assume it is), the safest way to do this is probably to set a "TERMINATE" flag somewhere and wake the worker threads. When the worker thread wakes up, first check this flag to see if it should terminate. If not then continue its work, but if it is, just find a way to exit the worker function. This is basically how you terminate a thread safely in C++.